# python regex group AttributteError

Tags: python

I'm working with regex on python and the following code seems not to work

```
import re                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
# my regular expressions                                                                                                
exprs = [ r"Gene ID: (.*)\,", r"(.*)\[Homo sapiens]",                                                                             
          r"from:(.*)\s",  r"NM_(.*)\.([0-9]+)" ,                                                                                
          r"NP_(.*)\.([0-9]+)\s", r"\,(.*)[^coding]exons",                                                                        
          r"AA length:(.*)\s", r"isoform(.*)\\NP" ]                                                                                                                                                                                             
# search for expressions vector in genetable                                                                            
with open('massaCHD8.txt', "r") as df:                                                                                      
   arq = df.read()                                                                                                     
for element in exprs:                                                                                                       
   resu = re.findall(element, arq, re.M|re.I)                                                                              
   for el in resu:                                                                                                             
       print(resu.group(0))
```

When I run the following scritpt I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "io2.py", line 17, in                                         print(resu.group(0))                                                 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of found strings/tuples, not a Match object. Therefore, if you want to print the match, you would use:

```
for element in exprs:                                                                                                       
   resu = re.findall(element, arq, re.M|re.I)                                                                              
   for el in resu:                                                                                                             
       print(el if isinstance(el, str) else el[0])
```

Comment: > If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import re                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
# my regular expressions                                                                                                
exprs = [ r"Gene ID: (.*)\,", r"(.*)\[Homo sapiens]",                                                                             
          r"from:(.*)\s",  r"NM_(.*)\.([0-9]+)" ,                                                                                
          r"NP_(.*)\.([0-9]+)\s", r"\,(.*)[^coding]exons",                                                                        
          r"AA length:(.*)\s", r"isoform(.*)\\NP" ]                                                                                                                                                                                             
# search for expressions vector in genetable                                                                            
with open('massaCHD8.txt', "r") as df:                                                                                      
   arq = df.read()                                                                                                     
for element in exprs:                                                                                                       
   resu = re.findall(element, arq, re.M|re.I)                                                                              
   for el in resu:                                                                                                             
       print(el)
```